# Multiplication in assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I am trying to create an assembly program that calculates the factorial of a number:

```
.data
n dword 1
res dword 1

.code
start:
mov ecx, 5
Top:
add n, 1
mov eax, res
mov ebx, n
mul eax, ebx
mov res, eax
dec ecx
jnz Top

Next:
Invoke crt_printf, addr res
```

The error I am encountering with the codes above is the mul part, where I want to multiply eax and ebx. How can I fix this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: _"The error I am encountering with the codes above is the mul part"_. And what, _exactly_, is the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want

```
mul ebx
```

The `eax` is implicit. What `mul ebx` does is `ebx*eax` and stores the result in `edx:eax` (the higher order bits go in `edx` when `eax` is not big enough to hold the result, in your example this is not a problem though).

Note that you have two parallel counters in `n` and `ecx`. You can get rid of one to make your code shorter:

```
.code
start:
mov ecx, 5
mov eax, 1
Top:
mul ecx
dec ecx
jnz Top
mov res, eax
```

Even shorter, you can replace the two lines `dec ecx, jnz Top` by `loop Top`. Now *that's* some short and sweet factorial function!